# Rotate prefix for external domain links using functions.php?

Tags: links

How to rotate from multiple prefixes for all links to a external domain https://externaldomainexample.com/

Our prefixes :

1. https://example1.com/api/xx/
2. https://example2.com/api?=xxxx&url=
3. https://example3.com/api/xx/

final url looks like - https://example1.com/api/xx/https://externaldomainexample.com/something-here...
OR
https://example2.com/api?=xxxx&url=https://externaldomainexample.com/something-here
OR
https://example3.com/api/xx/https://externaldomainexample.com/abcabc

There are few plugins in wordpress which insert the prefix but they allow for only 1 prefix.
How to achieve simple order rotation among these 3 prefixes using functions.php ?

Comment: you can do that with [array_rand](http://php.net/array_rand)

Comment: Kaperto thank you , but then how to detect external links ?